# AVAudioPlayer is turning nil

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8, avaudioplayer

Something is wrong with my code but I can't figure out what is wrong. If I compile the code everything is fine, but if I run the code I get this error:

```js
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

I've seen lots of the same questions but the answer to those questions is not useful in my case.

```html
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AudioToolbox



class ViewController: UIViewController{
   
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath:  Bundle.main.path(forResource: "beep", ofType: "wav")!))
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            
        } catch{
            print(error)
        }
        
        //standaard klaarmaaklijst
        nummerLabel.text = "\(schijnNummer)"
        nummerCheck()
    }

@IBOutlet weak var nummerLabel: UILabel!
}
```

I hope someone knows what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on? You're force-unwrapping the file path url it looks like.

Comment: The error is on the line: audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath:  Bundle.main.path(forResource: "beep", ofType: "wav")!))

Comment: That likely means there's a problem with that URL. The "!" Is a force unwrap. If the URL is not correct the force unwrap will try unwrap a nil and kill the application.

Comment: @JasperIJdema i have posted the answer please try. also check beep.wav file is present in main bundle or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Swift :**

```
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "beep", ofType:"wav") {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        do {

            let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()

        } catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

**Note:** Please check if the url is proper and not nil.